# Power Bi - Loading Data, Time and Reloading

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have been searching around and I could find something that was able to use as solution (probably I am too noob)

The Case

I try to combine multiple excel which contain data sheets.

The size is big and the rows many many....

I am at loading process for about  5 hrs now!

[image]

for example biscs_ean is data combination from multiple files name &_2019, &_2020, &_2021, &_2022 (which are not to be refreshed) and &_2023 which is to be updated in time to time.

biscs_ean is appended query by 2 queries, old files and 2023 file.

The only fquery that has Load activated is biscs_ean

this is the deal for the rest files.

Question 1.

Is there a way (understandable) that I could reduce time of uploading?

Question 2.

If I add a new query/table, is there a way that can Close & Apply, but the load process apply only to the new and avoid reloading?

I want the older tables to be available in data model.

PS files 2019 to 2022, have Load and Refresh disabled
file 2023 Load is disabled

Question 3.

If I update data in files _2023, can I refresh the specific data only, without biscs_ean gets data from _2019 (etc) again?

In general avoid reloading all over again.

Thanks in advance for your time and your help!

tables should aLready be loaded....